# This version of '@react-navigation/native' is not compatible with React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I have installed react-navigation via

```
npm install react-navigation
```

then i have installed @react-navigation/native via

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

but got an error

> This version of '@react-navigation/native' is not compatible with
>   React Navigation 5. Make sure you install 5.x version of
>   @react-navigation/native

```
npm -v @react-navigation/native
6.14.4
npm -v react-navigation
6.14.4
```

Comment: You have basically posted the version of npm you are using. To check the version of the package you have installed you need to look in your package.json. I would suggest editing your question and posting that

Answer (score 1):

In your app's package.json file check following dependencies and their versions. For me following resolved the above issue.

```
 "dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
"expo": "~37.0.3",
"react": "~16.9.0",
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
"react-navigation": "^4.3.9"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `@react-navigation/native` v5 and `react-navigation` together cause the `react-navigation` package is no longer being used after v4.

every module you want to use must have been installed separately.

for Example:
`@react-navigation/stack`, `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`, `@..../drawer` , ...

You either need some peer dependencies installed.

`react-native-screens`       to handle high performance navigation

`react-native-reanimated`    to handle transitions animations when you navigate through pages

`react-native-gesture-handler`      to handle navigations through pan gestures

`react-native-safe-area-context`    to handle screen controls

`@react-native-community/masked-view`   to handle particular styles on the header of the stack navigator

`@react-native-community/toolbar-android`     this is the android toolbar widget, you need to install it because it's being removed from 'react-native' core package from version 0.61